# Webaudio scriptProcessorNode function replacement

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am trying to record the output of a webaudio node to .wav.
Previously, I had been using recorderjs - which uses the `scriptProcessorNode` to capture the audio data but it seems like this has now stopped working.

The web audio API docs say that audio workers will be the replacement but are not implemented yet. Is it not possible to do custom processing at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

The `ScriptProcessorNode` allows for custom processing.  If your use of `ScriptProcessorNode` has stopped working without you having changed anything, you might want to file a bug about this with your favorite browser.